# Move a C++ library to all executor nodes from driver

Tags: apache-spark

I have a C++ library in my Spark driver. I would like to move that to all the executor nodes, where this library will be called.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the C++ library cannot be rewritten in a more spark friendly language for what ever reason, the best/reliable approach could be,

Wrap the C++ library as a service preferably exposing REST interface.

Then just use native REST calls to access the functionality.